# Semicolon as Super-comma

Tags: punctuation, commas, lists, semicolons

I hear I can use a semicolon as a "super-comma", where I'm listing three or more elements that have commas within them. I'm wondering, then, if this is correct:

> Our objective function is the annual cost of the abatement methods, which we plan to minimize; our decision variables are the amount of each abatement method we will use for each furnace type; and our constraints are such that our abatement methods are sufficient to achieve the designated amount of pollution control (and that the abatement methods are physically reasonable, i.e. no negative-height smokestacks).

I used the semicolons here because of the comma in the first element, which means the original list is of a "higher order" if you will. Then I matched all the commas of that order to avoid confusion. Am I doing this right?

Comment: Grammatically, it's correct. 

Stylistically? I'd either use commas throughout, treating the "which we plan to minimize" parenthetical *as* a comma; get rid of the which and its associated comma; or insert a which, and associated comma, before "we will use". In those last two cases, I would also delete the "and" before "our constraints"; the whole thing reads more as a series of independent clauses that honestly deserve their own sentences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. In fact, **using mere commas between independent sentences is generally advised against**. You have a number of independent sentences there, so semicola are the way to go. An independent sentence is a phrase that could otherwise stand on its own, with a capital at the beginning and a full stop at the end.

But the '**super-comma**' you read about is something else. Normally, one **should only use a semicolon between two phrases that are independent sentences**.

> We have opened the gates, liberated the Trojan prisoners, and hauled the horse inside.

You would **not** use semicola here, as these are not three independent sentences. Now let's make the sentence a little more complex:

> We have opened the impenetrable gates, never passed nor broken by an enemy, built long ago by our revered ancestors; liberated the Trojan prisoners and the many men from our other territories; and hauled inside the horse of the accursed Greeks, our ultimate victory.

As you can see, we still have three phrases that are not independent; nevertheless, we have **replaced the commas from the previous example with semicola**: otherwise, the sentence would be impossible to read. This is what they mean by using a semicolon as a super-comma. It is typically, but not exclusively, done when separating phrases that contain other commas within themselves.